# Desabilitar botão de download HTML5 Video

Tags: html5, google-chrome, html5-video

Após a atualização do Opera e do Chrome, usando a tag `video` passou a aparecer a opção de download do video, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como desabilitar isso? Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
     <video width="800" height="600" controls>
          <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Escondendo o botão com um Blob

Ao fazer um [*blob*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob) do vídeo e depois um parse para URL (usando [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURl)), o Google Chrome automaticamente esconde o botão:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Objeto XML
xml.open("GET", '/aqui-seu-video'); // Get do vídeo 

xml.responseType = "blob"; // Mudando o tipo de resposta para Blob

xml.onload = function (){
    if(xml.readyState === 4){
        if(xml.status === 200 || xml.status == 0){
            // Fazer um parse da resposta em url e passar para o source do <video>
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(xml.response); 
        }
    }
}
xml.send(); // termina a chamada
```

### Escondendo o botão com CSS

Esse botão pertence ao [*shadow DOM*](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) do elemento `<video>` no HTML5. Ao olhar sua árvore de elementos e seus respectivos estilos, com o uso do Google DevTools (após habilitar a opção de *"Show user agent shadow DOM"*), temos que o botão de download tem, por padrão, `32px`de largura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vemos também duas `div`: `-webkit-media-controls-panel` e `-webkit-media-controls-enclosure`. Sendo a segunda a *parent* da primeira.

Logo, basta que atribuamos a `...-enclosure` um `overflow: hidden`:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

E a  `...-panel` um `width: calc(100% + 32px)`:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel{
  width: calc(100% + 32px); /* + o tamanho do botão */
}
```

#### Exemplo

Com isso, basta atribuir os estilos acima a uma classe específica e usar quando necessário:

```css
video.non-downloadable::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure{
 overflow: hidden;
}
video.non-downloadable::-webkit-media-controls-panel{
  width: calc(100% + 32px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Apparently Non-Downloadable</h1>

<video controls width="500" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" class="non-downloadable" >
</video>

<h1>Downloadable</h1>

<video controls width="500" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4">
</video>
```

Obs.: Claro, quem quiser realmente baixar o vídeo, além de ter a opção do *context menu* (botão direito), pode mudar o estilo no DevTools, mas para uma primeira impressão é isso.

Answer (score -5):

Podes colocar na tag video  html controlsList="nodownload" e fará que não apareça a opção do download do mp4!

Comment: Isso é um recurso [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList), não é suportado pelo Firefox e nem pelo Safari e também **não é citado** no [WHATWG](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22controlsList%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhtml.spec.whatwg.org%2F)